# Ruby on rails get hours, minutes, seconds from two dates and times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need the number of hours, minutes, seconds between two dates and times.I'm able to get the number of days, hours, minutes, seconds but I don't want no.of days instead of it, I need hours, minutes, seconds only enough.

Here my code,

start_time is **Wed, 13 Dec 2017 20:35:19 -0800** and end_time is today datetime

```
def time_diff(end_time, start_time)
   diff = end_time - start_time
   mm, ss = diff.divmod(60)
   hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)
   dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)
   time = "%d h, %d m, %d s" % [hh, mm, ss]
   return time
end
```

**I need output like this "35 h, 29 m, 12 s"**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? How do you call your method, what result do you get and how does your expected result look like? Do you have any ideas why it is producing the wrong result? What have to tried to fix it?

Comment: BTW, `"%d h, %d m, %d s" % [hh, mm, ss]` obviously will never produce the string `"35 hours and 29 minutes and 12 seconds"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, a pure [almost] functional solution, without intermediate local variables:

```
start_time = DateTime.parse 'Wed, 13 Dec 2017 23:00:00 UTC'
end_time = DateTime.parse 'Wed, 15 Dec 2017 23:30:20 UTC'

sec, min, hrs = [60, 60, 1].
  map.
  with_object([[[end_time, start_time].
                  map(&:to_time).
                  map(&:to_i).
                  reduce(:-), nil]]) do |div, obj|
    obj << obj.last.first.divmod(div)
    obj[-2].rotate!
  end.
  map(&:first).
  compact

#⇒ [20, 30, 48]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the answer - just don't divide by 24!

Answer (score 0):

If the start_time and end_time are `DateTime` value you can use the following

```
difference = end_time - start_time
hours = (difference * 24).to_i
minutes = (difference * 24 * 60).to_i 
seconds = (difference * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
```

Comment: I have edited the answer. This will provide the correct output.